# Can't play m3u8 (HLS) on macOS Big Sur Safari

Tags: safari, http-live-streaming, m3u8

Copy following link to safari:
https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8

- Case1: macOS Big Sur  (11.0.1) + Safari (14.0.1 16610) x86 vm  ==>
  Can't play
- Case2: macOS Big Sur  (11.0.1) + Safari (14.0.1 16610) Applie M1 mac
  book pro ==> Can play some frames then stop
- Case3: macOS Catalina (10.15.17) + Safari 14.0.2 15610) x86 mac book
  pro ==> Can play well

Is it a bug of Big Sur safari?

Thanks